# How to change the application name in VisualVM?

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm

How can i change the application name in VisualVM ? I have multiple applications that where started from my IDE, but it's hard to distinguish them, there name are equal and the only difference is the PID. So i want to give them meaningful names, but the menu-item "Rename.." is disabled. How can i rename the application ? 
It seems to me like rename is only possible on snapshots -> [descripion of snapshots](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/applications_window.html)

[image: disabled "Rename" menu]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Rename** and **Remove** menu item are enabled only for snapshots not for applications.

If you want to change the name displayed for the application you can set if through a JVM command line arg when you launch your application :

```
-Dvisualvm.display.name=ApplicationName
```