# Changing an application's title in JVisualVM at runtime

Tags: java, jvm, visualvm, jvisualvm

As described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8414055/130758, I know it's possible to set the application display title in JVisualVM by using `-Dvisualvm.display.name=ApplicationName`.

But I'd like to know if it'd be possible for the application to update its visible title in JVisualVM at runtime.

Thanks

Comment: I'd like for whoever is asking for the question to be closed to thoroughly explain what is it that really is that hard to understand in the OP.

Comment: Based on the linked question it doesn't seem to be possible. You could [implement it yourself](https://visualvm.github.io/) if you're up for the task.